ng2 chart vertical bars not aligning
I am creating an Angular app and I can't align my vertical chart bars with the labels below the ox axis.
These are my Typescript methods responsible for the chart:
prepareChartData(expenses: ExpenseStatistic[]) {
  const uniqueCategories = [...new Set(expenses.map(expense => expense.categoryName))];
  
  this.barChartLabels = uniqueCategories;

  const colors = this.generateColors(uniqueCategories.length);

  this.barChartData = uniqueCategories.map((category, index) => {
    const categoryData = expenses
      .filter(expense => expense.categoryName === category)
      .map(expense => expense.value ?? 0); 

    return {
      data: categoryData,
      label: category ?? 'Unknown', 
      backgroundColor: colors[index] 
    };        
  });
}`

public barChartData: ChartDataset[] = [
    { data: [], 
      stack: 'a',
      label: 'Total Expenses',
      borderWidth: 1,
      barPercentage: 0.7,
      categoryPercentage: 0.9  
    }
  ];
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'category',  // Ensure this is set
        grid: {
          
          display:false
        }
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      }
    },
  };

This is my HTML code for the chart:
<div class="graph-card">
    <h3>Expense Trends</h3>
    <canvas
      baseChart
      [labels]="barChartLabels"
      [options]="barChartOptions"
      [legend]="barChartLegend"
      [datasets]="barChartData" 
      [type]="barChartType"
      [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
    ></canvas>
</div>

This is the way my chart looks right now:

I have tried to adjust the x axis properties. I am expecting the bars to be above the labels.

The lack of proper code formatting makes it difficult for readers to help you. Please [edit] your question to format inline code properly and to use a [code block] for any code or error messages you have included.

Late for the answer.
Your scenario is similar to this question: ChartJS Bar chart - Modify legend which displays the single bar in each category in the x-axis.
Depending on your dataset, you must provide the null value for the other category in the data array. For example, the data for the "updateWorks1115" category should be: [10, null, null].
The implementation for generating barChartData should be:
this.barChartData = uniqueCategories.map((category, index) => {
  const categoryData = expenses
    .map((expense) =>
      expense.categoryName === category ? (expense.value ?? 0) : null
    );

  return {
    data: categoryData,
    label: category ?? 'Unknown',
    backgroundColor: colors[index],
  };
});

You need to add skipNull: true in the barChartOptions to prevent an empty bar (space) is rendered. As the skipNull option is only available for the bar type, you need to change the ChartDataset and ChartOptions types (to their respective generic types) as below:
public barChartData: ChartDataset<'bar'>[] = [
  {
    data: [],
    stack: 'a',
    label: 'Total Expenses',
    borderWidth: 1,
    barPercentage: 0.7,
    categoryPercentage: 0.9,
  },
];

public barChartOptions: ChartOptions<'bar'> = {
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: 'category', // Ensure this is set
      grid: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    y: {
      beginAtZero: true,
    },
  },
  skipNull: true,
};

And remove the [type]="barChartType" from your <canvas> element.
<canvas
  baseChart
  [labels]="barChartLabels"
  [options]="barChartOptions"
  [legend]="barChartLegend"
  [datasets]="barChartData" 
  [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
></canvas>

Demo @ StackBlitz
